# Rails: respond_with the same template for two methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using jbuilder to create the view of my API, but many methods share the same jbuilder file:

```
module API
  module V1
    class DevicesController < ActionController::Base

    respond_to :json

    def create
      ...
      respond_with @device, status: 201
    end

    def update
      ...
      respond_with @device, status: 200
    end

  end
end
```

In the example bellow, `create` and `update` methods share the same view: *device_response.json.jbuilder*. I tried to add `template "devices/device_response"` just after `respond_to :json` but I get the following:

```
undefined method `template' for API::V1::DevicesController:Class
```

How can I define a unique jbuilder template response for two methods?

Thanks.

Comment: i think arguments to `respond_with` method should be a hash: `respond_with @device, status: 200, template: "devices/device_response"`

Comment: But i found in documentation that `respond_with` doesn't take template as argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`respond_with`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) doesn't take `template` as argument. For render the same template you can use example:

```
def create
  # ......
  respond_with(@device, status: 200) do |format|
    if @device.save
      format.json { redirect_to @device }
    else
      format.json { render 'devices/device_response' }
    end
  end
end
```

Why works [`respond_with(*resources, &block)`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with):

> If an acceptable format is not identified, the application returns a
>   ‘406 - not acceptable’ status. Otherwise, the default response is to
>   render a template named after the current action and the selected
>   format, e.g. index.html.erb. If no template is available, the behavior
>   depends on the selected format:

- for an html response - if the request method is get, an exception is
  raised but for other requests such as post the response depends on
  whether the resource has any validation errors (i.e. assuming that an
  attempt has been made to save the resource, e.g. by a create action)

  - If there are no errors, i.e. the resource was saved successfully, **the response redirect's to the resource i.e. its show action.**
  - If there are validation errors, **the response renders a default action, which is :new for a post request or :edit for patch or put.**